# How to get around not crashing when copying old version SQLite db to a newer version app

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I provided the option for my users to back up the sqlite db. The way I do it is by copying it to the external memory. They can load it back if they want it.

However, I am wondering how can I go around this situation:

If my user backed up the db in version 1. Updated the app to version 2 which is an altered db. Then my user load the db back (the older version one). This will cause the app to crash
Is there a way to
1- Detect what version of DB the user is copying so I compare it current db version and prevent the copying?
2- (even better) be able to update the copied version of DB to version 2 and load it to my app?

Any help in this is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have an application where I give to the user the ability to save the database. But, to avoid this kind of problem, I don't only "copy" the database file to save it, but I **write the data contained in the DB in another file (save file) in a particular way**, in other words, I created a new file format to store the exported data.

And, when I have to restore the exported data, all I have to do is to parse the save file, and insert the imported data in the database. So, I control what is exported and what is imported.

It's more complicated to implement, but I think it's the best thing to do.

Comment: Good suggestion but its kinda complicated. I was trying to figure out a way by dealing with what have. Thanks though +1

Comment: Or you also can do something like:
- Putting some info on the database to know which version it is
- Implement some kind of converter (v1 -> v2) when trying to import a v1 DB to a v2 programme